# Responsive table makes layout go beyond 100% width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, html-table

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdWrKX?editors=110

As you can see there is a responsive table inside ".panel" which you can scroll horizontally. Great.

But it makes the entire page expand horizontally and not fit in the window.
Try on small screens to see the bug.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="content content-primary content-sm">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table-bordered">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div>a</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>b</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Copyright</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrap {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#wrap > nav,
footer {
  display: table-row;
}

nav.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.content-sm {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.content-primary {
  background: #337ab7;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  text-wrap: no-warp;
}

td div {
  width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: I guess the `td div {width: 900px;}` is the problem. But the question is which behavior do you need for smaller viewports?

Comment: @FabianMebus –   900px is on purpose to simulate a td with lots of content. I have large tables which you can scroll horizontally, that works fine. But the overall layout should stay 100% of the window, instead of going beyond that.

Comment: You're using .container-fluid, but are you not using .row-fluid on purpose for your child row div ?

Comment: @BenoîtDaSilva – Bootstrap 3 does not use ".row-fluid" anymore.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNMzQy), it removes your 900px and instead adds content. The problem is you're forcing the table to a minimum of 900px, which means you are removing the responsiveness.

Comment: @sharf – you're not solving the problem. Please read previous comments before posting. The problem is with the layout properties, not the responsive table.

Comment: @murid I have read the question and previous comments. You are saying that the 'layout proprties' are to blame, not the responsive table. However, based on your question, and your provided code, the problem is in fact due to that 900px, so I tried to provide an example. If this is not the case, then please try re-wording your question to be more sepcific.

Comment: Here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/murid/hqcvvws2/ This one doesn't contain any table to avoid confusions, just a div that is 100% width with "overflow-x: scroll" and another one inside that is 9000px wide. Normally on a different type of layout, the parent div would be narrow and the child would scroll inside of it, but because there are those "display: table" on the overall layout, it doesn't work.

Comment: If I'm understanding your correctly, this issue has nothing to do with tables, responsive or otherwise. Which makes your question title incredibly misleading. I'd recommend re-visiting that. I'll take a look at your fiddle and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Ignoring the fact that the footer is not on the bottom of the page, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hqcvvws2/1/) what you're looking for? If it is I know the problem and can write up your solution.

Comment: Yes, that should be the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the child elements of `.content` seems to be ignoring % width values, the work around that worked for me was:

```
.content > * {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

I also added the class `.table` to your table element

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
```

[Here is a Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOxWxQ?editors=110)

**NOTE:** The `vw` unit only works in modern browsers. [Check support here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: `vw`, `vh`, and `vmin`/`vm` are a great unit. But keep in mind this is a solution for new browsers (IE10+).

Answer (score 1):

Change the table code like this:

```
<div class="content content-primary content-sm">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <div>a</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>b</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and remove this from your css file

```
td div {
  width: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the width of your td's child div like this

```
td div {
      width: auto;
    }
```

I hope it helps fixing the bug.

Comment: No – the responsive table works fine. The problem is the overall page layout.

Answer (score 0):

If the window size is less or equal to 900px the td content will go beyond that. You should not fix the td div size in px. Use instead % (percentage).

```
td div
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No – the responsive table works fine. The problem is the overall page layout.

Comment: Does the table size fits into the overall page layout size?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `table`s are by nature not responsive. You have resorted to using `display` `table`, `table-row`, and `table-cell` which are expanding beyond the veiwport with the content, and creating your undesired effects.

As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqcvvws2/4/): if you remove the `table` elements, your width issue goes away, but then you don't get the sticky footer you're looking for.

changing your CSS to:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;

}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #337ab7;
}

.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 51px; 
}

nav.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.content-sm {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.box-content {
    width: 9000px;
    height: 5000px;
    background: red;
}

.box-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

You will get your desired responsive width, as well as a full height webpage with sticky footer.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the content of the page has a dynamic height which means it can grow taller. Try making the content super tall, like 5000px and you'll see that "position: absolute" on the footer doesn't work anymore.

Comment: – thanks but that's not the original behaviour of the footer. Footer should go down with the content, not fixed. If you take the original code and make the content super tall you'll see how the footer behaves: it goes down, that is the desired result.

Comment: @murid updated again, I believe this is what you want.